# devise showing flash message in other pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, flash-message

After i sign in and then if i go to /users/edit page i get flash message
 "You have successfully signed in".

In registrations controller i tried:

```
flash.now  # either this or below one
flash.discard
```

same i tried for layouts like

```
    <% if flash[:alert] || flash[:error] || flash[:notice] %>
       <%= content_tag :div, :class => "alert alert-info info-inside" do -%>
          <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          <%= flash.now[:alert] if flash[:alert] %>
          <%= flash.now[:error] if flash[:error] %>
          <%= flash.now[:notice] if flash[:notice] %>
       <% end -%>
    <% end %>
```

Also if i create products and got to other pages it shows wrong flash messages.On refreshing it goes away.

Please tell me how to avoid such flash messages. I tried flash.now and flash.discard in my layout files and also in controllers that needed. but it didn't help me.

Comment: I know this ticket is old, however, did you resolve this and if so do you mind sharing how?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It checks to see if the flash message is actually present then grabs either the successful messages and error messages.

```
<% if flash.present? %>
<div id="flash" class="flash">
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
    <%= content_tag :div, msg, id: "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```